# How to add task at run time if task 1 is failed

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to execute task 2 if task 1 is success if task 1 fails i want to run task 3  and want to assign another flow if required.

Basically i want to run conditional tasks in airflow without ssh operators.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator,BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.models import Variable


def t2_error_task(context):
    instance = context['task_instance']
    if instance.task_id == "performExtract":
        print ("Please implement something over this")
        task_3 = PythonOperator(
            task_id='performJoin1',
            python_callable=performJoin1,  # maybe main?
            dag = dag
        )
        dag.add_task(task_3)
with DAG(
    'manageWorkFlow',
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        'owner': 'Mannu',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 4, 13),
        'schedule_interval':None,
        'depends_on_past': False,
    },
) as dag:
    task_1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='performExtract',
        python_callable=performExtract,
        on_failure_callback=t2_error_task,
        depends_on_past=True
    )
    task_2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='printSchemas',
        depends_on_past=True,
        python_callable=printSchemaAll,  # maybe main?
    )
    task_2.set_upstream(task_1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding tasks dynamically based on execution-time statuses is not something Airflow supports. In order to get the desired behaviour, you should add `task_3` to your dag but change its [`trigger_rule`](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules) to `all_failed`. In this case, the task will get marked as skipped when `task_1` succeeds, but it will get executed when it fails.

Comment: One more query  if my task 1 is failed then i want  assign a different flow like task_3 then task_2. Then how will i proceed please explain with the help of code.

Comment: In that case, you can set task_2 to be dependant on both task_1 and task_3 and set the trigger_rule of task_2 to be all_done. It will then wait for both task_1 and 3 to be either succes, failed or skipped

Comment: Hi Manmohan, did my suggestion indeed fix your issue? Glad to help further if it didn't. If it did, could you mark my answer as the accepted answer?

Comment: @Manmohan Upvoting the answer, although also very helpful, is different from accepting, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work